# ¿como puedo instalar tensorflow 1.12.0 para windows 10?

Tags: python, cmd, windows10, powershell, tensorflow

Le pongo esto en windows power shell con privilegios de administrador

`pip3 install tensorflow==1.12.0`

y me sale este error

````
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow==1.12.0 ```
````

Comment: Esta versión es bastante antigua, aunque si sabes porque la estás instalando y las razones, genial :)

Answer (score 1):

Puedes ser por dos motivos:

1. Tensorflow 1.12.x solo soporta hasta Python 3.6.x, si tienes instalada la última versión de Python no te funcionará, por lo que debes volver a la versión 3.6
2. Solo funciona con la versión de Python de 64 bits, la de 32 no te funcionará

Si aun así no te funciona pruebas estas otras formas de instalarlo:

- Instalarlo con pip `pip install tensorflow==1.12.0`
- Instalarlo con conda  `conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow==1.12.0`

Cabe la posibilidad de que al ser una versión tan antigua de Tensorflow, el propio Tensorflow y las distribuciones **lo hayan descatalogado**. En tal caso lo tendrías que descargar e instalar manualmente desde Github, [aquí el link](https://github.com/tensorflow/docs/tree/r1.1/site/en/api_docs)